# Facebook permission: Page Public Content Access and Social Wall

Tags: wordpress, facebook, permissions, rules

I made websites using Wordpress and the plugin Flow-Flow.  Everything worked well, but since April 24th and the new Facebook update I am getting this error message:

> (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

So, 3 weeks ago I applied for permissions on developers.facebook.com, but I still didn't hear anything from them. I still have this message.

Do I need the "Page Public Content Access" FB permission to do a Social Wall ? Facebook asks for App review, but this is a social wall. Does it do anything ?

If I actually need this permission, what can I do to get it?

This is a view from the configuration on the Plugin Flow Flow live streams. I can't configure several access tokens. I can just fill this felds. 
[image: Plugin Flow-Flow on Wordpress]

Comment: Of course it _is_ an app, because an app is the basis for using the API, so without an app you would not have anything here in the first place. _“This is just a social wall.”_ - which still can mean a lot of different things/different implementations - so please be precise, otherwise this isn’t answerable to begin with. I am assuming that you do not only want to show posts from pages you have admin access to? Then oembed would probably be the way to go.

Comment: I wasn't sure if we could call it an App. I do access to only pages where I am admin, but I have a lot of pages with bags of followers.

Comment: If you only need to read posts from pages you have admin access to, then you don’t necessarily need PPCA; granting `manage_pages` permission would be enough for that - but you would still need to get your app’s use of that permission reviewed then, and the plugin you are using would have to support this (using page access tokens for the requests) as well. I’d suggest to contact the plugin author to figure out whether this is supported somehow, or could be implemented for a future version.

Comment: The plugin Flow-flow Social Streams support already the access token. But I don't know why they need PPCA. but they ask for it, and since they asked I get this error #10 from Facebook.

Comment: It can’t work using “the” access token, you would need to use the matching page token for every single page that you want to get data from (and would therefor need to make an individual request for each of those pages as well.) _“But I don't know why they need PPCA. but they ask for it”_ - they are not asking for that specifically; this is just the API response they get returned, because the API could not determine that you indeed have admin access to the page(s) in question.

Comment: I just edit my question. You're able now to see the parameters on my plugin. I understant it would be better to do a single token for every page but I cannot...

Comment: If you can only use one token, then this approach will not work for multiple pages - even though you have admin access to them, there is no way for the API to know that (except for the one page whose page access token you are using), so in this case it will again look as if you were trying to access content from arbitrary public pages, so in this case you would indeed need to submit for access to PPCA first.

Comment: And how can I make the process going quicker to get the PPCA ? because I asked FB 3 weeks ago...

Comment: You can’t, everybody is sitting in the same boat when it comes to app review. First come, first serve. Plus, since these are recent changes that require review for a lot of apps, even old existing ones, they are probably quite inundated at the moment, so patience is the only virtue right now. (Although might not hurt to double-check if you actually successfully submitted for review - sometimes people get tripped up by the UI showing some error somewhere, and then they wait forever for feedback …)

Comment: CBroe, thank you. I'll let the question open in case i can have another isssue but thank you for helping me.